# Build libpcap for Python 2.7.x in windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7-x64, wireshark, libpcap, pcap-ng

I've tried several different things and crawled around on lots of forums looking for an answer to this question.

My goal is to simply parse through a wireshark .pcap-ng trace file using Python. From what I can gather, it seems like I need a libpcap wrapper for Python or perhaps WinCap (PyCapy?)

I'm relatively new to Python, so if you all have any pointers on how to install this module please let me know. Earlier I had a 32bit version of Python installed and found a win32 installer and was able to parse through .pcap files but I really want to be able to parse through the .pcapng files. Thanks guys,
~Kyte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is Windows, so WinPcap won't help; libpcap 1.1.0 and later can read pcap-ng files, but there is currently no version of WinPcap based on a version of libpcap with pcap-ng support.

I.e., currently, the first piece of software to try would be [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org), [Parallels Workstation](http://www.parallels.com/products/workstation/), or [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/overview.html), and the next piece of software to try would be some Linux distribution running on your Windows machine under the virtualization software.  Sorry.

(Yes, I have to find the time to do some libpcap infrastructure work to make it easier for the WinPcap people to make their remote capture support work with newer versions of libpcap.  Sadly, there are only 24 hours in a day, and a ton of other things to do competing for the hours that remain after such frivolities as eating and sleeping. :-))

A workaround for that *particular* issue would be either to save a capture from Wireshark in pcap format rather than pcap-ng format or to use Wireshark tools such as editcap (which *can* handle pcap-ng files on Windows, as they don't use libpcap/WinPcap to *read* capture files) to convert from pcap-ng to pcap.

There are a couple of Python wrappers for libpcap/WinPcap - [python-libpcap](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pylibpcap/) and [Pcapy](http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy).  The python-libpcap page has a daemon and a penguin on it, so they're only advertising BSD and Linux support; it might work on other UN*Xes, as there shouldn't be major differences in the way you hook into libpcap, but might not work on Windows.  Pcapy, however, explicitly mentions WinPcap and Win32 binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Do try out the pcap binary that @dirkloss compiled for Python 2.7 | Windows.

[Here](https://twitter.com/dloss/status/368101423634210816)

I tried it , but I'm getting this error- [SO qn](http://t.co/QnENkPstgV)

Comment: I wound up developing (with great success) in a java environment using JNetPcap. Learning python is still on my to-do list.